# Using plus and add operands with strings Clojure

Tags: clojure

Is there a way to use the `*` and `+` operands with strings in Clojure?

For example:

```
(defn times [a b] (* a b))

=> (times x y)
Desired Output: x*y
```

OR

```
Desired Output: xy
```

Comment: Why is `(defn * [a b] (str a b))` not working?

Comment: The error that I am getting basically says a var can not be cast into a number

Comment: Other languages define that behaviour as `3*'AB' => 'ABABAB'`, but multiplying two strings is something you have to come up with. I'd be glad, that Clojure is no coming up with something. Just define that functionality yourself.  Also `str` does what you expect for `+` to happen (I assume)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem:

```
(defn * [a b]
  (if (and (string? a) (string? b))
    (str a b)
    (clojure.core/* a b)))

WARNING: * already refers to: #'clojure.core/* in namespace: user, being replaced by: #'user/*
=> #'user/*
(* 4 5)
=> 20
(* "A" "B")
=> "AB"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're using Clojure on the JVM.

The function `*` only works with numbers.
You can convert a String into a number by parsing it to the right type:

```
(def int1 (Integer/parseInt "1"))
(def double1 (Double/parseDouble "1.0"))
(def product1 (* int1 double1)) ;; 2.0
;; or
(def int2 (clojure.edn/read-string "1"))
(def double2 (clojure.edn/read-string "1.0"))
(def product2 (* int2 double2)) ;; 2.0
```